# Android: Dynamically added button's text missing

Tags: android, button, text

I wrote a view A extends ViewGroup, then i added a button to this view A. But the text of button seems not in a good layout. 
So i did these (mPrint is my button):

```
 mPrint.setText(R.string.print);
    mPrint.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.print_action_bg);
    mPrint.setSingleLine();
    mPrint.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    mPrint.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

then the text "Print" is missing.
I deleted the mPrint.setSingleLine(), text is back but in the top of button. Anybody knows what happend? BTW, all i want to do is show the text in the center of button.

Comment: Remove the setGravity and setPadding methods and see what is shows.

Comment: Could you show more code?
If you override ViewGroup directory, you would override onLayout

Comment: can you show me your "A extends ViewGroup " class code ?

Answer (score 0):

```
String str=getResources().getText(R.string.print).toString();
mPrint.setText(str);
```

Comment: i tried, still missing. and i delete setSingleLine, text's appeared upper of the button.

Comment: Debug the value of 'str'.

Comment: As @abnormal says, TextView#setText(int) is a valid method if int is resource ID

Comment: i debuged, when i setText(), the value of str is "Print".